# Show that $\sum_{pq\leq x}\frac{1}{pq}$ = $(\ln \ln x)^2+O(\ln \ln x)$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I know that $\sum_{pq\leq x}\frac{1}{pq}$=$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}\sum_{q\leq\frac{x}{p}} \frac{1}{q}$=$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}(\ln\ln(\frac{x}{p})+A+O(\frac{1}{\ln (\frac{x}{p})}))$. However, I'm stuck at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: @reuns look here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} = \ln \ln x + O(1), \qquad \sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p}\frac{\ln p}{\ln x} = O( \ln\ln x)$$

$$\ln \ln (x/p) =\ln ((1-\frac{\ln p}{\ln x})\ln x)= \ln\ln x+O(\frac{\ln p}{\ln x})$$

$$\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{x/p<q\le x} \frac{1}{pq}  = \sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} (\ln \ln x - \ln\ln (x/p)+O(1)) = O(\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p})+O(\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} \frac{\ln p}{\ln x})= O(\ln \ln x)$$

$$\sum_{p q\le x} \frac{1}{pq} =\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ q \le x} \frac{1}{pq}-\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ x/p<q\le x} \frac{1}{pq}  = (\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p})^2+O(\ln \ln x)$$

Comment: isnt $$\sum_{p q\le x} \frac{1}{pq} =\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ q \le x/p} \frac{1}{pq}$$Why di you write $$\sum_{p q\le x} \frac{1}{pq} =\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ q \le x/p} \frac{1}{pq}-\sum_{p \le x, x/p<q\le x} \frac{1}{pq}  = (\sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p})^2+O(\ln \ln x)$$?

Comment: $\sum_{p q\le x} \frac{1}{pq} =\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ q \le x} \frac{1}{pq}-\sum_{p \le x}\sum_{ x/p<q\le x} \frac{1}{pq}$

Comment: Hello reuns is the edit i made according to your answer valid?

Comment: I think I erased your edit with mine (you don't have enough reputation to edit instantly)

Comment: no in my original post i gave an alternate solution based on yours

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-standard way to show it:

By Merten's estimates:

$$\sum_{pq \leq x}  \frac{1}{pq}  \leq \left( \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} \right)^2 = (\ln \ln x)^2 + O(\ln \ln x).$$

We just have to show that the constant in the leading term is $1$. That is, for every $c < 1$, there is $x$ sufficiently large so that:

$$\sum_{pq \leq x} \frac{1}{pq}  \nleq c (\ln \ln x)^2 + O(\ln \ln x).$$

By Merten's estimates again,

$$\left(\ln \ln \sqrt{ x }  + A + O\left(\frac{1}{\ln \sqrt{ x } }\right)\right)^2 =  \left( \sum_{p \leq \sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{p} \right)^2 \leq  \sum_{pq \leq x}  \frac{1}{pq}.$$

However, the following is true: for any $c < 1$, there is a sufficiently large $x$ such that:
$$
  \ln \ln \sqrt{ x } = \ln \frac{1}{2} \ln x \geq c \ln \ln x.
$$
To see this, we replace the inner $\ln x$ with $x$.
$$
\ln \frac{1}{2} x \geq c \ln x \iff \frac{1}{2} x \geq x^c \iff \frac{1}{2}\geq \frac{1}{x^{1-c}}.
$$
As $c < 1$, the last inequality is clearly true for large $x$. So the constant of the leading term is at least $1$.

Comment: You may also use $\ln \ln \sqrt x  = \ln \left( {\frac{1}{2}\ln x} \right) = \ln \ln x - \ln 2$ in the second half of your proof.

Comment: That is much faster!