# Asymptotic bound for $\log \left(1 - \frac{\log p}{\log {x}} \right)$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

This appears in this question: [Show that $\sum_{pq\leq x}\frac{1}{pq}$ = $(\ln \ln x)^2+O(\ln \ln x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138316/show-that-sum-pq-leq-x-frac1pq-ln-ln-x2o-ln-ln-x)

Here, $p$ is a prime that is less than a natural number $x$.

In that question, it is said that $\log \left(1 - \frac{\log p}{\log {x}} \right) = O\left(\frac{\log p}{\log x}\right)$.

However, I am not aware of a way to do it.

If the above estimation is too tight, then I only wish to bound it to be
$$\log \left(1 - \frac{\log p}{\log {x}} \right) = o(\log \log x)$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with $\log p/\log x,$ except the value is positive. If $0<y,$ then $\log(1+y)<y.$ This follows from $$e^{y}=1+y+y^2/2+\cdots \geq 1+y,$$ and then taking $\log$ of both sides.  $e^y\geq 1+y$ is actually true for all real $y,$ but it takes a *little* more work.

Comment: The $o(\log\log x)$ is true, too, because $\log(p)/\log(x)<1,$ while $\log\log x\to\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\log(1-y)=-y-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}-\ldots,$$  by Maclaurin series, where $y<1$. Then

$$\log(1-y)=-y+O(y^2)=O(y),$$ where we have $|y| < 1$, as higher order terms go to zero quickly.

Since $p < x$ and $\log$ is an increasing function, we have $\log(p)<\log(x)$ or $0 < \frac{\log(p)}{\log(x)} < 1$, assuming $x \gt p \gg 1$. Consequently,
$$ \log\left(1-\frac{\log(p)}{\log(x)}\right)=O\!\left(\frac{\log(p)}{\log(x)}\right).$$